# web3, nodejs - How to put decimals values ​into the toBn function

Tags: tokens, erc-20, sendrawtransaction

I want the amount of tokens to be a decimal number.
but i heard that toBn is not supported decimals number.

When I put in a decimal number, I faced the following error:
while converting number 0.15 to BN.js instance, error: invalid number value. Value must be an integer, hex string, BN or BigNumber instance

How can I send a decimals amount of tokens to my wallet?
I am a beginner and save me.
plz help!

i used code:

```
const val = 0.15; // this guy
let decimals = web3.utils.toBN(info.decimal);
let amount   =  web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toBN(val).mul(web3.utils.toBN(10).pow(decimals)));
```

Comment: There are many similar questions in this forum. See for example https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/72481/31933

Comment: `BN` supports only integer values!

Comment: so you want to send a transaction with 0.15 currency? why use BN?

Comment: @Pave Is there a nodejs in module that can send a decimal amount? not BN?

Comment: See my answer. I hope it helps :D

Answer (score 5):

Just don't use BN. You need to convert ETH to WEI.

This is a very simple proccess. Web3 has some buildt in functions for this:

```
const val = 0.15; // this guy
var weiAmount = web3.toWei(val);
```

Comment: This doesn't work for example with custom tokens that have less than 18 decimals. Ex If I want to calculate 0.2 of a BTC or 0,5 of USDC

Answer (score 2):

From [the official documentation](https://github.com/indutny/bn.js/#usage) of `BN`:

> Note: decimals are not supported in this library.

Here, the term *decimals* refers to numeric values with digits after the decimal point (i.e., non-integers).

When creating a `BN` object, you can pass either an integer or a string which represents an integer.