# How do I get the decimals of an erc20 contract when the decimals variable is not there?

Tags: web3js, contract-development, erc-20, dapps

What is the best practice for doing this?

In the ERC20 standard having a `public decimals: uint256` is marked as optional.
But obviously you cannot display a token balance in the UI without having the `decimals`.

So how should I handle the case where the decimals field is not there? Should I just assume the contract implements 18 decimals?

What is the standard here? Is it safe to say that 95% of contracts implement the `decimals` variable?

Comment: Yes. And the remaining 5% (typically very old ones, before it became a standard to conform with the standard) are implementing either `Decimals` or `DECIMALS`. What is the address of the token which you are having this issue with?

Comment: It's general purpose. A user adds an address for an erc20 contract and I want to be able to infer what the decimals for that contract is. So it's safe to assume that the decimals variable will be there? I am happy to accept 5% redundancy.

Comment: So try `decimals` first. Then `DECIMALS`. Then `Decimals`. Then default to 18. If you need help with coding it using web3.js, then let know.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of decimals is purely for user-friendliness - inside the blockchain there are no decimals. That's why it's optional.

If there are no decimals then you simply display what the token amount inside the contract shows - things get easier than with decimals. So it behaves like `decimals` was 0.

This concept is rather confusing for many people. You can read more for example here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/72481/31933

Comment: I understand what the decimals are for. What I want to do is know how to parse the uint256 on the UI if there are no decimals specified. If the decimals are 18 you can divide it by 10^18. If there are no decimals variable in the contract, then what is the best method for obtaining what the intended decimals are. e.g. the token list standard suggested by uniswap.

Comment: This user is clearly interested in `decimals` for offchain purpose and not for onchain purpose (quote: "obviously you cannot display a token balance in the UI without having the `decimals`").

Comment: As I said, if there are no `decimals` you have to assume it's 0 - unless you explicitly see in the source code something else (which would be rather strange). So you display the same number you get from the contract

Comment: I would actually say default to 18 (because of how ETH is regarded everywhere). But I guess it's subjected to opinion.

Comment: Well you can of course display whatever you want, but I do think the "right" thing would be to display as 0 decimals.