# Is the function of transferring a fraction of ERC20 token going to work in smart contract?

Tags: solidity, erc-20

For a `ERC20` token with `decimal=18`, there are plenty of decimal to handle something like `10.234`. Here is a function to transfer a percentage of a balance:

```
uint256 public balance;  //in token
address public payable recipient;

function transferOnePercentage() public payable returns (bool) {
   ERC20token.transfer(recipient, balance * 1 / 100);
   return true;
}
```

When `balance=525` and one percent is 5.25, is this function `transferOnePercentage` going to work and send `5.25` token to `recipient`?

Comment: What do you mean `balance;  //in token`?

Comment: `balance` is the account token balance.

Comment: In what units???

Comment: For a ERC20 token with decimal=18, an amount of 525 is practically zero. You'll be transferring 5 wei instead of 5.25, both are practically zero, and the difference betwen them by itself is practically zero.

Comment: unit is ERC20 token. 5.25 is 5 and a quarter.token. It is represented as 5.25 for user and stored as 5.25 * 10**18.

Comment: Then your `balance` shouldn't be 525, it should be 525 followed by 18 zeros (and 1 percent of that is going to be 525 followed by 16 zeros)!

Comment: ERC20 `decimals` is a variable that should be used **only for off-chain purposes**, for example, when displaying a balance in your dapp. You should convert your amounts to wei resolution when you send them as input to an ERC20 contract function, and back to token resolution when you receive them as output from an ERC20 contract function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to calculate 1% of erc20 18 decimal token?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/72479/how-to-calculate-1-of-erc20-18-decimal-token)