# What is going on with this XBT token?

Tags: tokens, price

So, I have this token called XBT, Elastic Bitcoin, in my wallet. 0x64fB96d0395f6bf105F35233911e3dF2C5bf4Ce8 Is the contract address. My address is 0x9B3De9eF1AbB57750e762e8c0762BF86a2F21033. Etherscan says that I have 9 of them, each worth $741. This is surprising, because MetaMask says I have .00014 of them, worth .01107. Other wallets say other things entirely. What is going on here and what is the true value?

Comment: XBT is an elastic token and has rebase functionality (the token supply and balances change based on something) https://defiprime.com/elastic better to ask them on their telegram channel https://t.me/elasticbitcoin don't give you private key or seed to anyone

Answer (score 0):

If you go to https://etherscan.io/address/0x64fB96d0395f6bf105F35233911e3dF2C5bf4Ce8#readProxyContract and enter your address at the "balanceOf", you get a reply of 14402. Because the token has 8 decimals, this is the same as .00014 which Metamask displays (well, it should display 0.0001402, but maybe it rounds the value, or you didn't copypaste all of it).

To understand how decimals in tokens are used, you can read various articles online, or have a look at my previous answer https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/72481/31933 .

As for the value - difficult to say what it is, since that depends on many things. Also one place may show a different value from another. The value is simply the amount someone is (or has been) willing to pay for it.