# How to get uniswap quote using a fractional input amount

Tags: javascript, ethers.js, uniswapv3

i have a question about interacting with the Uniswap quoter contract.

I am able to get a quote using [quoteExactInputSingle](https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/reference/periphery/interfaces/IQuoter#quoteexactinputsingle). The method has 1 parameter for the *input amount*, which works fine when it is an integer like `100`. The contract parameter is a `uint` (therefore we must use something equivalent in javascript that can be converted using [jsbn](https://github.com/andyperlitch/jsbn)/[jsbi](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/jsbi)).

Does anyone know how to get quotes using **fractional** input amounts instead? E.g. wanting to swap `0.00014 UNI` in javascript:

```js
const amountIn = 0.00014;
await quoterContract.callStatic.quoteExactInputSingle(
  token0Address,
  token1Address,
  poolFee,
  amountIn,  // The parameter for input amount
  0
);
```

produces:

```
Error: invalid BigNumber string (argument="value", value="0.00014", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.7.0)
  reason: 'invalid BigNumber string',
  code: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT',
  argument: 'value',
  value: '0.00014'
}
```

---

I have tried finding the answer in the uniswap source code:

- [front-end](https://github.com/Uniswap/interface), inc. [the widgets repo](https://github.com/Uniswap/widgets)
- [AWS router](https://github.com/Uniswap/swap-router-contracts)
- their [SDK docs](https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/reference/periphery/lens/Quoter)
- their [guide on making trades](https://docs.uniswap.org/sdk/2.0.0/guides/trading)

I did notice that [the uniswap product](https://app.uniswap.org/#/swap) **multiplies decimal amounts** by 20 decimal places (before sending the amount in a http request to their API), which is then converted "back" to a decimal in a smart contract (after they identify the number of decimal places for the input token). This is obviously because the EVM doesn't support fractions, however i can't find an explanation for *why* the multiplication is done to exactly 20 decimal places.

I do also know about the `Token` sdk class, e.g.:

```js
const token = new Token(5, token0Address, 18, 'UNI', 'Uniswap');
```

However i haven't found a way to use the `Token` instance with the quoter contract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just needed to convert the token ***balance*** to token ***amount*** in the contract call, silly me :). Theres [no such thing as fractional tokens](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/72481/110684).

```js
const amountIn = 0.00014;  // before
const amountIn = new Decimal('0.00014e18').toString();  // after. This specific token in this example has 18 decimal places

await quoterContract.callStatic.quoteExactInputSingle(
  token0Address,
  token1Address,
  poolFee,
  amountIn,
  0
);
```

I also figured out that the uniswap front-end *caches* quotes to an extent, hence i was getting thrown off with seeing token amount being passed in as `0.00014e20` instead of `0.00014e18` in the http call history.